# Why does ClassUtils use `IdentityHashMap` and not `HashMap` in its fields (Spring framework)?

Tags: java, spring, hashmap

Why does `primitiveWrapperTypeMap` field of a class `ClassUtils` (org.springframework.util.ClassUtils) use `IdentityHashMap` and not `HashMap`?
The `Class<T> Object` is singleton, `equals()` to other class is always **false**, in `HashMap` the key also not covered, why use `IdentityHashMap` and not `HashMap`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `IdentityHashMap` used for better performance. I'll try to briefly explain it.

In a typical `Map` implementations, `equals()` is used to compare keys (while you access/put/search keys) as the `Map` interface obligates to do so. Also, `HashMap` uses the `hashCode()` method for hashing.

But the `IdentityHashMap` class violates these rules. According to documentation, this is a simple **linear-probe hash table** with peculiarities:

- it uses reference equality (==) for key search operations,
- it uses the `System.identityHashCode()` method during search operations.

Al these 'tricks' allow `IdentityHashMap` demonstrate a better performance.

If you look at the code, `primitiveWrapperTypeMap` is used in a `static` block, and it is filled with values such as `<Integer.class, int.class>`, etc. So, this field is used only inside of a class, and it is immutable from outside of a class. That's why it is safe to use `IdentityHashMap`.